# React Storybook not Recognizing a Story

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, storybook

I am testing a react app with storybooks. For some reason my custom story is not loading properly. If I write my custom story in `1-Button.stories.js` is renders but if its in `2-MyFunction.stories.js`, it doesn't render

In the `src/stories` directory, I have 3 files:

`0-Welcome.stories.js`

`1-Button.stories.js`

`2-MyFunction.stories.js`

This is my `.storybook/main.js`:

```
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],//similar to config.js
  addons: [//similar to addons.js
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
  ],
};
```

Here is the `MyFunction.stories.js`:

```
import MyFunction from '../Components/MyFunction;

export const Functiontest = () => <MyFunction .../>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't include the code for the tab name

```
export default {
    title: 'function'
};
...

export const functiontest = () => {
    return <My function ...>
}
```

Comment: Please provide detail answer as your question.